# Why can't I bind to this dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I don't understand why I can't bind my **custom** width dependency property (of my custom control) to another custom control dependency property.

I followed all guidelines I'm quite sure dependency properties are well implemented.

Both Window (BlackAndWhiteWindow), Canvas (all of them are **custom** controls, not those from wpf) inherits from control.

Any suggestion? I'm going mad...

Visual studio error states that is impossible to bind the property because you can only bind a dependency property to a dependency object, but they are dependency objects and i'm binding to dependency properties!!

**EDIT 1:**

**XAML**

```
<test:BlackAndWhiteWindow x:Class="GSdk.TestGsdkShared.TestWindow" x:Name="bwWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:windows="urn:gsdk-net"
             xmlns:test="clr-namespace:GSdk.TestGsdkShared"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Width="320" Height="240"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <windows:Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=bwWindow, Path=Width}" Height="100">
    </windows:Canvas>
</test:BlackAndWhiteWindow>
```

**Control class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using GSdk.Net.Lglcd;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;
using GSdk.Shared.Windows.Properties;

namespace GSdk.Shared.Windows
{
    public class Control : DependencyObject, IDisposable
    {
        private volatile bool m_Disposing;

        public Control()
        {
            /*Font = new Font(
                "monospace",
                12.0f,
                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
            );*/
        }

        public static Property<Font> FontProperty = new Property<ContentControl, Font>(c => c.Font, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Font("monospace", 12.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
        public static Property<int> WidthProperty = new Property<ContentControl, int>(c => c.Width, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
        public static Property<int> HeightProperty = new Property<ContentControl, int>(c => c.Height, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public Font Font
        {
            get { return FontProperty[this]; }
            set
            {
                if (Font != null && Font != value)
                    Font.Dispose();
                FontProperty[this] = value;
            }
        }
        public int Width { get { return WidthProperty[this]; } set { WidthProperty[this] = value; } }
        public int Height { get { return HeightProperty[this]; } set { HeightProperty[this] = value; } }
        public virtual DeviceTypes DeviceType { get { return DeviceTypes.Invalid; } }
        public bool Disposing { get { return m_Disposing; } protected set { m_Disposing = value; } }

        #region Dispose handling
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Disposing = true;
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Managed resources
            }

            // Unmanaged resources
            try
            {
                if (Font != null) Font.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        ~Control()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Canvas class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using GSdk.Net.Lglcd;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;
using GSdk.Shared.Windows.Properties;

namespace GSdk.Shared.Windows
{
    public class Canvas : Layout, IDrawable
    {
        public Canvas()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public static Property<int> TopProperty = new AttachedProperty<Canvas, int>(() => TopProperty, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
        public static Property<int> LeftProperty = new AttachedProperty<Canvas, int>(() => LeftProperty, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
        public static Property<int> BottomProperty = new AttachedProperty<Canvas, int>(() => BottomProperty, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
        public static Property<int> RightProperty = new AttachedProperty<Canvas, int>(() => RightProperty, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public static void SetTop(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TopProperty, value);
        }
        public static int GetTop(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(TopProperty);
        }
        public static bool IsSetTop(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj.GetValue(TopProperty) != default(int));
        }

        public static void SetLeft(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(LeftProperty, value);
        }
        public static int GetLeft(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(LeftProperty);
        }
        public static bool IsSetLeft(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj.GetValue(LeftProperty) != default(int));
        }

        public static void SetBottom(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(BottomProperty, value);
        }
        public static int GetBottom(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(BottomProperty);
        }
        public static bool IsSetBottom(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj.GetValue(BottomProperty) != default(int));
        }

        public static void SetRight(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RightProperty, value);
        }
        public static int GetRight(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(RightProperty);
        }
        public static bool IsSetRight(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj.GetValue(RightProperty) != default(int));
        }

        public Bitmap Draw()
        {
            // FIXME: This should be changed, is temporary
            //MessageBox.Show(Width.ToString() + " " + Height.ToString());
            Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, 0, 0, Width, Height);
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    int x, y;
                    x = y = 0;
                    IDrawable drawableItem = item as IDrawable;
                    DependencyObject dependencyItem = item as DependencyObject;

                    if (dependencyItem != null && drawableItem != null)
                    {
                        if (IsSetTop(dependencyItem))
                            y = GetTop(dependencyItem);
                        else if (IsSetBottom(dependencyItem))
                            y = Height - GetBottom(dependencyItem);

                        if (IsSetLeft(dependencyItem))
                            x = GetLeft(dependencyItem);
                        else if (IsSetRight(dependencyItem))
                            x = Width - GetRight(dependencyItem);
                        g.DrawImage(drawableItem.Draw(), x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Window class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using GSdk.Net.Lglcd;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;
using GSdk.Shared.Windows.Properties;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GSdk.Shared.Windows
{
    public abstract class Window : ContentControl, IDrawable
    {
        private Action m_DispatcherDrawHandler;
        private Thread m_DrawThread;
        private Bitmap Background = QvgaDevice.CreateValidBitmap();

        public Window(Applet applet = null)
        {
            m_DispatcherDrawHandler = new Action(DispatcherDrawHandler);
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                Applet = new Applet()
                {
                    Autostartable = false,
                    SupportedDevices = DeviceType,
                    Name = GetType().FullName,
                };
                Applet.Connect();
                Applet.GetDevices<DefaultDeviceCollection>().Qvga.ForegroundApplet = true;
                Applet.GetDevices<DefaultDeviceCollection>().Qvga.AppletPriority = AppletPriorities.Alert;

                m_DrawThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrawHandler));
                m_DrawThread.Start();
                //Dispatcher.Hooks.DispatcherInactive += new EventHandler(Hooks_DispatcherInactive);
            }
            else
            {
                Applet = applet ?? CreateApplet();
                //if (Applet == null) throw new NullReferenceException("CreateApplet() must return a not null value");
            }
        }

        private void DispatcherDrawHandler()
        {
            Applet.GetDevices<DefaultDeviceCollection>().Qvga.Update(Draw());
        }

        private void DrawHandler()
        {
            while (!Disposing)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(m_DispatcherDrawHandler);
                Thread.Sleep(33);
            }
        }

        /*private void Hooks_DispatcherInactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
            }));
        }*/

        protected abstract Applet CreateApplet();

        //public readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
        public Applet Applet { get; private set; }
        public override DeviceTypes DeviceType { get { return DeviceTypes.Qvga; } }

        public virtual Bitmap Draw()
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Background))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, Background.Width, Background.Height));
                g.DrawString("Hello World", Font, Brushes.White, new PointF(0f, 0f));

                IDrawable ctrl = Content as IDrawable;
                if (ctrl != null)
                    g.DrawImage(ctrl.Draw(), 0, 0);
            }
            return Background;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            lock (Applet)
                if (Applet != null) Applet.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Property class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Windows;

namespace GSdk.Shared.Windows.Properties
{
    public struct Property<T>
    {
        Property(DependencyProperty prop)
        {
            m_DependencyProperty = prop;
        }

        readonly DependencyProperty m_DependencyProperty;

        public static implicit operator Property<T>(PropertyBase prop)
        {
            return new Property<T>(prop.DependencyProperty);
        }

        public static implicit operator DependencyProperty(Property<T> prop)
        {
            return prop.m_DependencyProperty;
        }

        public T this[DependencyObject obj]
        {
            get { return (T)obj.GetValue(m_DependencyProperty); }
            set { obj.SetValue(m_DependencyProperty, value); }
        }
    }

    public abstract class PropertyBase
    {
        public readonly DependencyProperty DependencyProperty;

        protected PropertyBase(DependencyProperty prop)
        {
            DependencyProperty = prop;
        }
    }

    public sealed class Property<TContainer, TValue> : PropertyBase
    {
        public Property(Expression<Func<TContainer, TValue>> accessor)
            : base(DependencyProperty.Register(accessor.MemberToString(), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer)))
        {
        }
        public Property(Expression<Func<TContainer, TValue>> accessor, PropertyMetadata metadata)
            : base(DependencyProperty.Register(accessor.MemberToString(), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer), metadata))
        {
        }
        public Property(Expression<Func<TContainer, TValue>> accessor, PropertyMetadata metadata, ValidateValueCallback callback)
            : base(DependencyProperty.Register(accessor.MemberToString(), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer), metadata, callback))
        {
        }
    }

    public sealed class AttachedProperty<TContainer, TValue> : PropertyBase
    {
        public AttachedProperty(Expression<Func<Property<TValue>>> accessor)
            : base(DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(accessor.MemberToString().Substring(0,accessor.MemberToString().Length - "Property".Length), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer)))
        {
        }
        public AttachedProperty(Expression<Func<Property<TValue>>> accessor, PropertyMetadata metadata)
            : base(DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(accessor.MemberToString().Substring(0, accessor.MemberToString().Length - "Property".Length), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer), metadata))
        {
        }
        public AttachedProperty(Expression<Func<Property<TValue>>> accessor, PropertyMetadata metadata, ValidateValueCallback callback)
            : base(DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(accessor.MemberToString().Substring(0, accessor.MemberToString().Length - "Property".Length), typeof(TValue), typeof(TContainer), metadata, callback))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these `Property<T>` and `AttachedProperty<T, U>` classes you are using? They don't seem standard... if they're not real dependency properties, WPF won't know how to use them.

Comment: You are right sorry I forgot to put them, http://pastie.org/2930172 Maybe the problem is connected to the fact that I'm using "implicit operator", but I used that way to create a dependency property to make it refactor friendly

Comment: Post your code **in the question**.

Comment: I don't see the problem about posting it on pastie (which is built to do this type of things), I'm posting code in the question but you will see the problem (it's long).

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: when (not if) pastie goes away your question becomes worthless.

Comment: And to your question, the problem is your `Property` and `AttachedProperty` classes are not `DependencyProperty`s. They emulate their behavior and wire them up but ultimately the Visual Studio Designer doesn't know what is going on and dies. Does it work at runtime?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: What sixlettervariables said, also if you have too much code that often is a sign that you have not worked on localizing your problem enough yet.

Comment: @H.B.: Well infact I don't know where the problem exactly is. sixlettervariables: I'm trying, can you post it as an answer so evenutally I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that it's connected to the fact that I'm using a class that is emulating a dependencyproperty (the property struct), while it's not directly a dependency property. Solved by using the normal dependency property